# Java was started but returned exit code=14

Tags: java, android, sdk

I installed the SDK Tool in my windows 7 64 bits laptop, and I got that error. 
Java was started but returned exit code=14

Here is the info I have in my eclipse.ini file

```
   -startup
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
   --launcher.library
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
   -product
   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256M
   -showsplash
   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256m
   --launcher.defaultAction
   openFile
   --launcher.appendVmargs
   -vmargs
   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=7
   -Xms40m
   -Xmx768m
   -Declipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
   -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: Try to increase `-Xms` and `-XXMaxPermSize` (btw the last one seems to be duplicated)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a typo:

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=7

should be:

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7

Also, for eclipse to work Java 7 or later must be installed